# Perforce P4V Adding a new file to the depot

Tags: perforce

I'm new to Perforce but I was able to successfully create a depot with a whole directory tree. Now I'm trying to add a file to one of the folders within that tree and I'm having trouble finding how to do that. I can see the file in the Workspace tab when I navigate through my computer but when I right-click the file there's no option to add it to a Pending Changelist. Appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Tony

Edit: I feel like I'm making hash of this thing. So I created a new workspace and located the folder containing the file I wanted to add. Then I right-clicked the file and selected "Mark for Add". Then I went to submit and got this error:

//depot/main/SSRS/1 SQL Code/Voucher Query.docx - warning: cannot submit from non-stream client
No files to submit.
Submit failed -- fix problems above then use 'p4 submit -c 5'.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer shows how to add a file from the command line, but you were asking how to do it with P4V.

If you right click the file in your Workspace view you should see the option "Mark for Add".  You can also use the toolbar button with a small red + sign, 4th from the left.

Comment: Okay, so when I right-click the file in the Workspace tab I get the following choices:  Open, Open With, Delete Local File, Diff Against..., Show in Explorer, Open Command Window Here

Comment: Hmm - does your Perforce account need a login ?  It's possible that you won't see options that update the depot if you're not logged in.

Comment: Thanks Gareth, but I've been able to check files in and out -- I've been testing the capability with Visual Studio and it's really quite easy, I'm just stumped how to add to my file repository. I'm sure it's something simple, but I literally just downloaded the program today so I'm still sorting it all out. I'm also able to login to the workspace from my co-workers PC (I installed P4V client on hers and was able to attach to the server I installed on my PC) so I think I'm logging in alright.

Comment: Sorry I can't be more help here.  One other thing you could try is to drag the file from the Workspace tree to a pending changelist; you might at least get a meaningful error.

Comment: It's okay, I think I'm getting the hang of it now, seems like the key is getting the new files to show up in that workspace pane, once they're there it seems to work well. Thanks again for your help, I'm really glad I found this resource today.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is in the folder, run:

```
p4 add foldername/file
```

Then you can

```
p4 submit
```

Answer (score 0):

Your depot is a stream depot (the icon should have "waves" in it...)

Set up a new depot, a "local" one, and use that one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it just worked by logging off, killing the task in Task Manager and finally re-starting my Perforce.